# how to Access ASP.NET Gridview ItemTemplate in CodeBehind?(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i need to change the dropdown's selected value in code behind ,but i don't know how
this is my grid view's code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="216px"  >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="family" SortExpression="LastName" />
                            <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="132px">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">one</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">two</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">five</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="8">eight</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">three</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="7">seven</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">zero</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">four</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="9">nine</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When do you need to set the `SelectedValue`? If during databinding you can use `RowDataBound` to find it. Since it's in an `EditItemTemplate` of a  `TemplateField` you need to look for `DataControlRowState.Edit`:

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit AndAlso e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dropDownList1 = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
        dropDownList1.SelectedValue = "7"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks,but is there anyway to do in normal way?not in Gridview1_RowDataBound event.i have a problem with binding gridview.i choose a field as drop down's selected value then i need to bind gridview again,during binding an exception occure,so i need to set all gridview's dropdowns(in each row)selected value into null.is there any way?

Comment: Using `RowDataBound` _is_ the normal way if you databind a `DropDownList` in a `GridView`. It's visible only after the grid switched to edit-mode anyway.

Comment: i have this problem in PageIndexChanged event ,so ,what can do??i need to set all rows dropdown's selected value into null in PageIndexChanged event

Comment: _What_ problems do you have? You haven't mentioned problems or errors in your question. You haven't even mentioned that the paging causes trouble. Why don't you edit your question in a way that everyone knows what exactly goes wrong? You should also provide the relevant code. Otherwise it's difficult to help. Apart from that, you have to `DataBind` the grid in `PageIndexChanged` anyway which causes `RowDataBound` to be triggered for every row. If one of these rows is in edit-mode my code will set the `SelectedValue`.

Comment: @user3091887: you cannot set the `SelectedValue` to `null`. I assume you want to deselect all items. Then you just have to set `DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1`